# Properly set admin notices

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm building a shipping plugin for which I need to **only** notify admin if something went wrong with an order.

What is the recommended way to add/ store notices( not from user) when something like this happens so when admin checks there would be an error?

I've tried the following but not sure how it works on demand..

```
$result = $this->__make_soap_request($bill);
          if(!$result) return WC_Admin_Notices::add_custom_notice('billl_error','<div id="message" class="error notice notice-error is-dismissible"><p>Error creating waybill</p><button type="button" class="notice-dismiss"><span class="screen-reader-text">Dismiss this notice.</span></button></div>');
          elseif($result->Bill->Result == false)
          {
            WC_Admin_Notices::add_custom_notice('billl_error',sprintf('<div id="message" class="error notice notice-error is-dismissible"><p>CreateWayBillResult: %s</p><button type="button" class="notice-dismiss"><span class="screen-reader-text">Dismiss this notice.</span></button></div>',$result->Bill->Result->Message));
            remove_action('wc_custom_createbill', [$this, 'createbill'], 1, 0);
            return false;
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to store an option/flag somewhere to keep the admin notice displayed until it is dismissed. So when a problem occurs, you'll want to do something like:

```
<?php
  if( !$result ){
    update_option( 'billl_errors', 'Error creating waybill' );
  }
```

Then, you'll check for that in the admin_notices hook and display it as needed:

```
<?php
  function my_has_billl_errors(){
    if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && get_option( 'billl_errors' ) ){
      sprintf(
        '<div class="notice notice-error is-dismissible"><p>%s</p></div>',
        get_option( 'billl_errors' )
      );
    }
  }
  add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_has_billl_errors' );
```

You'll want something to handle when the message is dismissed (it should `delete_option( 'billl_errors' )` or set a user meta to hide it for that one user (if you need others to see it as well).

Of course, extend this to suit your needs, but this is the way to do it. Then, whenever there is an error, any admin user will see that message so long as that option is in the database.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better implementation would be using a class "Bill_Error_Message":

```
class Bill_Error_Message {
    private $_message;

    function __construct( $message ) {
        $this->_message = $message;

        add_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this, 'render' ) );
    }

    function render() {
        printf( '<div class="updated">%s</div>', $this->_message );
    }
}
```

This allows you to instantiate the message at any time prior to rendering:

```
if ( $error ) {
    new Bill_Error_Message( "Error creating waybill" );
}
```

Comment: question...if this is triggered but the user's action...would the admin see this when he logs into admin at another interval?